# SQL - set difference and getting fields that aren't a part of the difference

Tags: sql, oracle, set-difference

I have a query that basically performs something like this:

```
select a, b, c
from tab
where tab.state = 'A'
minus
select a, b, c
from tab
where tab.state = 'B'
```

In this example, `a`, `b`, and `c` are the key fields of this table. `state` is also a part of the key, and I'm trying to find situations where there is a record in state A and not in state B. There is another field (not in the key) that I'd like to report on, `value`, that might be different for the same record in different states. Example:

```
a  b  c  state  value
---------------------
1  1  1  A      12
1  2  2  A      1002
1  3  9  A      43
1  1  1  B      17.34
1  2  2  B      1002
```

In this case, I'm interested in the row whose key is `1,3,9` where state is A. I'd also like to get the value of the `value` column, but if I try:

```
select a, b, c, value
from tab
where tab.state = 'A'
minus
select a, b, c, value
from tab
where tab.state = 'B'
```

What I would get returned is two rows:

```
a  b  c    value
----------------
1  1  1      12
1  3  9      43
```

Basically, I want to have `value` in the result set, but not participate in the `minus`. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but maybe I'm just too tired to get it... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way to do this is like this:

```
select a, b, c, value
from tab
where tab.state = 'A' and not exists (
  select 1                          -- let the optimizer do its thing
  from tab ti
  where tab.state = 'B' and ti.a=tab.a and ti.b=tab.b and ti.c=tab.c)
```

I would even add a `distinct` in the outer query if the data can have doubles.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all rows where `state = 'A'` with the matching ones with `state = 'B'`...

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.value, t2.value v2
FROM (SELECT a, b, c, value FROM tab WHERE state = 'A') t1
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT a, b, c, value FROM tab WHERE state = 'B') t2
            ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.c = t2.c
```

...and then pick the rows where there were no match:

```
 SELECT a, b, c, value
 FROM ( /* previous query */ )
 WHERE v2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a,
  b,
  c,
  value
FROM tab tab1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT a, b, c FROM tab WHERE tab.state = 'A'
  MINUS
  SELECT a, b, c FROM tab WHERE tab.state = 'B'
  ) tab2
ON tab1.a  = tab2.a
AND tab1.b = tab2.b
AND tab1.c = tab2.c
```

I believe above code would do the trick.